# Data is missing when change page - react js antdesign table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, antd

i got a problem. When i try to change to second page on the table, the data is missing from the api. i dont know why this happer. I'm using react js and antdesign table for my project.
When first load, data is load perfectly, but when i click next to the second page, the data is appear, than missing. i try to check the API response, but the data is empty. in the postman, data is appear

```
import { Card, Button, Space, Table, Modal, Col, Row, Form, Input, Select, message} from 'antd';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axiosInstance from '@xxxxx/services/axiosInstance';

export default function ManageUser() {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const [detailModalOpen, setDetailModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState({});
  const [roleOptions, setRoleOptions] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserList();
    fetchRoleOptions();
  }, [page, pageSize, searchText]);
  
  const fetchUserList = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get('/user/list', {
        params: {
          page: page,
          per_page: pageSize,
          search: searchText,
        },
      });
      const responseData = response.data.data.data;
      setDatas(responseData.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching user list:', error);
    }
  };

  const handlePageChange = (current) => {
    setPage(current);
  };

  const handlePageSizeChange = (current, size) => {
    setPage(1);
    setPageSize(size);
  };

  const handleSearch = (value) => {
    setSearchText(value);
  };

  const fetchRoleOptions = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get('xxxxx/api/role/gets?search');
      const responseData = response.data.data;
      setRoleOptions(responseData.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching role options:', error);
    }
  };

  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    axiosInstance.delete(`/user/remove/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        fetchUserList();
        message.success('User Deleted Successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
      });
    console.log(id)
  };

  const detailUser = (id) => {
    axiosInstance
      .get(`/user/detail/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setDetailData(response.data.data);
        console.log(detailData)
        setDetailModalOpen(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error fetching user detail:', error);
      });
  };

  const createUser = (values) => {
    const { name, email, password, role_id } = values;
    const newData = {
      name,
      email,
      password,
      role_id,
    };

    axiosInstance
      .post('https://xxxxx/api/user/create', newData)
      .then(() => {
        fetchUserList();
        setOpen(false);
        message.success('User Created Successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating user:', error);
      });
  };

  const editUser = (id) => {
    const user = datas.find((item) => item.id === id);
    const role = datas.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (!user && !role) {
      return;
    }

    Modal.confirm({
      title: 'Edit User',
      centered: true,
      content: (
        <Form
          layout="vertical"
          name="basic"
          autoComplete="off"
          initialValues={{ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: role.name }}
          onFinish={(values) => updateRole(id, values)}
        >
          <Form.Item
            label="Name"
            name="name"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter a name' }]}
          >
            <Input placeholder="Name" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Email" name="email" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter an email' }]}>
            <Input placeholder="Email" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Role ID" name="role_id" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select a role' }]}>
            <Select placeholder="Select Role">
              {roleOptions.map((role) => (
                <Select.Option key={role.id} value={role.id}>
                  {role.name}
                </Select.Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
            Save
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => Modal.destroyAll()}>Cancel</Button>
        </Form>
      ),
      width: 500,
      cancelButtonProps: { style: { display: 'none' } },
      okButtonProps: { style: { display: 'none' } },
    });
  };

  const updateRole = (id, values) => {
    const { name, email, role_id } = values;
    const updatedData = {
      name,
      email,
      role_id,
    };

    const url = `/user/update/${id}`;

    axiosInstance
      .put(url, updatedData)
      .then(() => {
        fetchUserList();
        message.success('User Updated Successfully');
        Modal.destroyAll();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error updating role:', error);
      });
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Email',
      dataIndex: 'email',
      key: 'email',
    },
    {
      title: 'Role Name',
      dataIndex: 'role_name',
      key: 'role_name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      render: (text, record) => 
        <Space size="middle">
          <a onClick={() => editUser(record.key)}>Edit</a> |
          <a onClick={() => deleteUser(record.key)}>Delete</a> |
          <a onClick={() => detailUser(record.key)}>Detail</a>
        </Space>
    },
  ];
  
  const data = datas.map((item) => ({
    key: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    email: item.email,
    role_name: item.role_name
  }))

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <Button style={{float: 'right', margin: 8}} type='primary' onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Add User</Button>
        <Input.Search
          placeholder="Search"
          allowClear
          onSearch={handleSearch}
          style={{ width: 200, marginBottom: 16 }}
        />
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
          scroll={{ x: 1500 }}
          pagination={{
            current: page,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            showSizeChanger: true,
            pageSizeOptions: ['10', '20', '30', '50'],
            onChange: handlePageChange,
            onShowSizeChange: handlePageSizeChange,
            total: datas.length,
            showTotal: (total, range) => `${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total} items`,
          }}
        />
        <Modal
          title="Add New User"
          centered
          visible={open}
          onOk={() => setOpen(false)}
          onCancel={() => setOpen(false)}
          width={1000}
          footer={null}
        >
          <Form
            layout="vertical"
            name="basic"
            autoComplete="off"
            onFinish={createUser}
          >
            <Row>
              <Col span={6}>
                <Form.Item label="Name" name="name" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter a name' }]}>
                  <Input placeholder="Name" />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={6}>
                <Form.Item label="Email" name="email" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter an email' }]}>
                  <Input placeholder="Email" />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={6}>
                <Form.Item
                  label="Password"
                  name="password"
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter a password' }]}
                >
                  <Input.Password placeholder="Password" />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={6}>
                <Form.Item label="Role ID" name="role_id" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select a role' }]}>
                  <Select placeholder="Select Role">
                    {roleOptions.map((role) => (
                      <Select.Option key={role.id} value={role.id}>
                        {role.name}
                      </Select.Option>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Cancel</Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          title="User Detail"
          footer={null}
          centered
          visible={detailModalOpen}
          onOk={() => setDetailModalOpen(false)}
          onCancel={() => setDetailModalOpen(false)}
          width={800}
        >
          <p>Name: {detailData.name}</p>
          <p>Email: {detailData.email}</p>
          <p>Role Name: {detailData.role_name}</p>
        </Modal>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I try so hard to find on google how to fix it. but i cant. Hope you all can help me. Thankyou